# Retrieving contents of the grid

Tags: jqgrid

I am using [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) to display values on the client side. Initially the grid is empty and the user enters the data inline. According to the requirement, I need to submit the data once the user submits the form.

I intend to, just prior to submitting the form, format contents so that I can store the user entered details in the database. Is their any way I can get a grid data in the form of JSON?

Currently I am doing the same in the following way:

```
var ids = $(gridId).jqGrid('getDataIDs');
for ( var i =1; i <=ids.length; i++) {
        var id = ids[i];
        rowData = $("#"+grid).jqGrid('getRowData',id);          
    }
 //add rowData to some global object and inturn to some hidden field and sending it the server.
```

Is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to use

```
var gridData=$("#list").jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
```

to get full data from the grid. After you have all the data in one JavaScript object `gridData` you can modify it in the way which you need prior to submitting to the server.