# jqGrid clientArray

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to use jqGrid clientArray to submit multiple updates at once. (I am trying to update multiple rows in one go).

```
        onSelectRow: function(id){
            if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                jQuery('#fnlusetaxlistings').saveRow(lastsel, true, 'clientArray');
                jQuery('#fnlusetaxlistings').editRow(id, true, null, null);
                lastsel = id;
            }
        },
```

This works fine, but I have no idea that how to retrieve clientArray and send it to the server? If anyone can post an example of sending clientArray to server, it will be very helpful.

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 4):

There are no "clientArray", but there are 'data' parameter which is object with all local data. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958415/retrieving-contents-of-the-grid/4971590#4971590) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4485970/jqgrid-rowobject-inconsistencies/4486142#4486142) answer for examples.